# Activity Toolbar not behaving correctly in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, toolbar, android-appcompat

I am creating a app with NavigationDrawer and Fragments. I created NavigationDrawer project in Android Studio. In my main activity, I have added a FrameLayout container which gets replaced by a fragment. I have a fragment A which gets inflated as soon as the MainActivity starts.

The Problem:
The toolbar of the MainActivity doesn't behave properly. The views in Fragment A don't detect a toolbar and hence the ***overlap*** over the MainActivity's toolbar.

Another Problem is that the toolbar ***shows 2 menus***, one from the main activity and another from the Fragment A. However I just want to show the menu from fragment A.

What can I do to solve it?

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_a.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint" />



            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Login"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment A.java**

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle("Login");

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "loginFragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.login_fragment_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_register) {
            mMainActivityInterface.onOpenRegisterFragmentButtonClicked();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: does your @layout/app_bar_main also has a toolbar?
Do you want to have two toolbars ?

Comment: It seems you have toolbar defined in both fragment.xml and activity.xml, remove the toolbar tag from activity.xml, you can also check for layout calls in activity class to prevent toolbar inflating from activity, and call in only fragment.